# Struts Plugin from JBoss Tools in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, struts, eclipse-kepler, jboss-tools

I installed JBoss Tools for Eclipse Kepler but I cannot find Struts plugins (there are spring and JSF only)

I absolutely need Eclipse Kepler but how to install the missing Struts plugins?

Thanks

Comment: According to [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-13618) struts was removed from JBoss Tools in release 4.1

Comment: Is there a way to reinstall them ? If I download jboss tools full suite they are there, but using another eclipse version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint, but we removed the Struts tools since for years they have not been kept uptodate (only some very old struts 1 version), had zero bug reports or feature requests or forum questions thus seemed noone used/cared for them.

Details are in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-13618.

Comment: aaagghh , I loved them so much , perhaps Im the only one in the world using that :(